# Routing to Javascript/CSS Files?

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc-4

In my current project I needed to make a new .NET MVC controller that is passed a parameter. I want this new controller to use the same javascript files as the original home controller.

RouteConfig.cs

```
        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );

        routes.MapRoute(
           name: "Controller2",
           url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
           defaults: new { controller = "Controller2", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
       );
```

Here is the Controller2 code:

```
public class Controller2 : Controller
{

    public ActionResult Index(int id)
    {
       //do stuff here
        return View("~/Views/Home/Index.cshtml");
    }
}
```

When I access Controller2 via this link: http://localhost/AppName/Controller2/index/1

The application navigates to the correct index file but looks for the css files in a location where they are not, namely:
http://localhost/AppName/Controller2/index/dist/css/app.css

The files the index for Controller2 are really in:

http://localhost/AppName/dist/css/app.css

It must have something to do with my Routing but I can't figure it out.

How do I fix this problem?

Thanks,
Matt

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use absolute, or even better, application relative links for your styles:

```
<link href="~/dist/css/app.css">
```

Note the "~". If the URL that ends up in the browser does not start with a `/` or a scheme, it will be relative to the current URL of the page.

Comment: Thank you! This fixed the issue I was having!